# Save base64 encoded pdf on server with php

Tags: php, pdf, base64

I have a call to a web service that gives me a response back in the format of a base64 encoded pdf file. I need to save the pdf to a folder on the server.

I can't get the document saved in the folder. It always saves the file locally on the computer and not to the server.

Here is the code i have at this moment.

```
header('Content-type: application/pdf');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="doc-'.$document.'.pdf"');
file_put_contents('~/pdf/'.$document.'.pdf', $wc->out->document);
```

Does someone have a suggestion where i can find the solution?

thx

Comment: If you're trying to save the file onto the server, why are you outputting headers that prompt your browser to download it?

Comment: thx Nick, i have changed it just was so into the problem that i did not see it properly anymore ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Headers are for serving data to the client - you don't need these. Just use `file_put_contents`

As for the file save location, you know that will save into a folder within the user profile? If you want the current folder, use `.` instead of `~`.

Comment: Hi Adam, thx for the info. That was something i also tried but the problem stay's so it still not saves the file into the folder. The permission is set to 777 so it is writable.

Comment: Have a look in the php error log - that will tell you either that it can't find the source file or can't write to the target.